# How to add string into the designated position?

Tags: vim

Line:
I am here.
I want to add string `ok` from the 12th column in the Line.

The vim script `:s/$/  ok` works fine.
If the Line is `Iamhere.`,the vim script change into `:s/$/    ok`.
How to write a smart command to do the job?

Answer (score 1):

\%12c will match the 12th column, so :%s/\%12c/ok/ will insert "ok" in the 12th column in every line of the file.

See :help pattern-overview